# opencv crop Mat, but allocating new ptr in the process

Tags: opencv, vtk

I am cropping an opencv Mat:

```
cv::Size size = img.size();
cv::Rect roi(size.width*/4., size.height/4.,size.width/2., size.height/.2);
img= img(roi);
```

I then use `img.data` pointer to create a `vtkImageData` (via `vtkImageImport`):

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport> importer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport>::New();
importer->SetImportVoidPointer(img.data);
...
importer->Update();
vtkImageData* vtkImg = importer->GetOutput();
```

I don't get the expected result when I display the vtkImg. I've digged into opencv's code and the problem is that when creating the cropped data, opencv does not allocate a new pointer that is 4 times smaller but instead keeps the same already allocated block, advances the pointer upstream and flags the new `img` variable as not continuous. Therefore my vtk image still imports data from the original uncropped Mat. I know I could import the full image to vtkImageData and then do the cropping with a vtk filter but I would prefer not to.

Is there a way with opencv to obtain a cropped image that is "physically" cropped (with a newly allocated data pointer)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`cv::Mat::clone()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-clone). It makes a deep copy of the underlying image data and returns a `cv::Mat` object which contains said data.

You would then change the line

```
img= img(roi);
```

to

```
img = img(roi).clone();
```

After which `img` contains only the cropped data.